# Can't Configuring Flutter firebase messaging

Tags: flutter

I'm New to flutter and I get course to how make an uber clone app , so I reach to the point that to make push notification by flutter firebase messaging, and I can't configure it the version I have is 10.0.0.. please help I have been searching for solution since days.

here is my dart file I created for configuring firebase messaging:

```
class PushNotificationService {

  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  Future initialize () async{
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage :(Map<String, dynamic>message)async{
        print('onMessage: $message');
      },
    onLaunch :(Map<String, dynamic>message)async{
    print('onLaunch: $message');
    },
      onResume :(Map<String, dynamic>message)async{
        print('onResume: $message');
      },

    );


  }
  Future <String> getToken()async{
  String token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
  driversRef.child(currentFirebaseUser.uid).child("token").set(token);

  firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("alldrivers");
  firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("allusers");
  }
}
```

Is there any possible ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that firebase_messaging version `10.0.0` has updated methods. These include handlers when the app is:

- in the background but not terminated
- terminated
- open

For more info you can follow this tutorial that uses version `10.0.0` - [Setup Cloud Firebase Messaging](https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/)